# Azerothcore. How to unlock spells Seal of Vengeance/Seal of Corruption, warhorse/summon warhorse for training by other races?

Tags: azerothcore, world-of-warcraft

Is there any way to make paladin spells seal of vengeance/seal of corruption available for learning by other races? (other than dwarves, humans, draeneis/ blood elves)
Same thing for Warhorse/Summon Warhorse spells.

I've tried to look in DBC files to find some clues for the root of this problem. Any column, raceMask, flag that is responsible for making this spells exclusive for certain races. I found nothing, only flags Alliance/Horde only but this is not very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is solved! If you have simillar problem you need to change raceMask of your spell in SkillLineAbility.dbc
DONT FORGET TO REWRITE DBC IN YOUR PATCH AND ON SERVER SIDE!